# Certificate error when running on a wearable device Gear s3 with tizen studio 2.3

Tags: certificate, tizen, tizen-web-app, samsung-galaxy-gear

I'm developing a web application with Tizen Studio 2.3 for wearable v3.0, the application runs normally in the emulator, however, when I want to run a physical device, Gear s3, which if recognized in the IDE, I get a Certificate error, as is, as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xBtnnwL7-M

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have Samsung Wearable Certificate Extension installed on Package Manager ? 
To find Wearable Certificate Extension, go to Package Manager > Extension SDK > then check

Comment: Samsung Wearable Certificate Extension and Samsung Certificate Extension if they are installed.

Comment: Did you install these already ?